# Encrypt DB2 table data while at reset . Compatible with z/linux and Z/os

Tags: encryption, db2

I have been tasked with finding a solution to encrypting DB2 table data while at rest (DAR)

My environments:
  Note: all environments using SSL to encrypt DB2 data while in transit

1) I have two z/os environments with two tables in scope.  My client request a specific column have its data encrypted while at reset.

-- One of the tables utilizes SQL replication and is not only dependent on two z/os environments but two DB2 z/linux based db2 instances and tables

2)  DB2 LUW is deprecating DB2 table column encryption and advocating the use of Native database encryption.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to encrypt DB2 data while at rest that is compatible between z/os and luw (In my case I am using z/linux). Ideally any solution would be transparent to applications.

Comment: Db2 native encryption is transparent to applications. What do you mean saying "compatible between z/os and luw"? Why db2 native encryption is not suitable for you?

Comment: Mark -  One of the involved table is stored on z/os and z/linux and it data replicates between the two AND then replicates to another z/os environment.  

My initial requirement was to encrypt one column of one table.  This is available on z/os but is deprecated in the LUW world.   That said,  I am looking for a solution that encrypts DB2 table data at rest and is compatible on different Operation systems, in my case that is z/os and z/linux.   What ever that solution is the user community that access the data will also have to implement the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, Db2 encryption is transparent to applications, including yours. Once data leaves "rest" (storage) it is decrypted, then re-encrypted when it comes to "rest" again.

Encryption implementation details are platform-specific. In your case the entire databases on z/Linux must be encrypted to protect your single column. Given that you are using SQL replication, no other changes are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the [Row and column access control (RCAC)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0057423.html) feature.
You may encrypt the column values for users which don't have an appropriate authorization, but allow to see actual values for others (including the replication user).
But column data on disk and in a backup are not encrypted with RCAC.
Use native encryption to encrypt entore database on disk. You don't have an ability to use native encryption just for particular columns and tables.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with `Mustaccio` and `Mark`. Yet another possible choice is federation, i.e. you don't use replication at all but rather leave the data in their respective places and let the databases sort out data access for consumers, e.g. via `DRDA` or `Data Virtualization Manager` for `z/OS`.